# free software to remove background noise(Nosie of horns, other public disturbances) from video i shot

Tags: windows-7

Free software to remove background noise(Noise of horns, other public disturbances) from video I shot, I tried Movavi but its free edition doesn't help much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process that I have used with very good results goes as follows:

1. Use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) to split the Video and Audio to separate files
2. Use [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) to deal with the noise by using noise filters, high/low filters & patching sections over.
3. Use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) to recombine the two files.

Both FFMPEG & Audacity are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Available for most platforms including Windows